# Getting error while trying to plot graphs

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a function to plot multiple graphs, when i try and plot them separately it works fine, but when trying to call the function and plot all I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'
```

Here is my code

```
def plot_averages(morning_dict , night_dict):
    plt.plot(date_value.keys() , date_value.values() , "g." ,   label = "Hourly value")
    plt.plot(morning_dict.keys() , morning_dict.values() ,"r*",  label = "Daily mean")
    plt.plot(night_dict.keys() , night_dict.values() ,"b*",  label = "Night mean")
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Value")
    plt.title(file_name)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

The dicts I'm trying to plot:

```
morning_averages =
{Timestamp('2022-09-18 06:00:00'): 7.125,
 Timestamp('2022-09-19 06:00:00'): 3.8}

night_averages =
{Timestamp('2022-09-18 18:00:00'): 5.216666666666668,
 Timestamp('2022-09-19 00:00:00'): 3.816666666666667}

date_value =
{'2022-09-18 06:00:00': 5.4,
 '2022-09-18 07:00:00': 6.0,
 '2022-09-18 08:00:00': 6.5,
 '2022-09-18 09:00:00': 6.7,
 '2022-09-18 10:00:00': 6.9,
 '2022-09-18 11:00:00': 7.9,
 '2022-09-18 12:00:00': 8.5,
 '2022-09-18 13:00:00': 7.5,
 '2022-09-18 14:00:00': 7.9,
 '2022-09-18 15:00:00': 7.8,
 '2022-09-18 16:00:00': 7.6,
 '2022-09-18 17:00:00': 6.8,
 '2022-09-18 18:00:00': 6.4,
 '2022-09-18 19:00:00': 5.7,
 '2022-09-18 20:00:00': 4.8,
 '2022-09-18 21:00:00': 5.4,
 '2022-09-18 22:00:00': 4.7,
 '2022-09-18 23:00:00': 4.3,
 '2022-09-19 00:00:00': 4.1,
 '2022-09-19 01:00:00': 4.4,
 '2022-09-19 02:00:00': 4.3,
 '2022-09-19 03:00:00': 3.8,
 '2022-09-19 04:00:00': 3.5,
 '2022-09-19 05:00:00': 2.8,
 '2022-09-19 06:00:00': 3.8}
```

What did i miss? All help appreciated

Comment: Hi Lana. Please try to help us more with this question. If you can post a reproducible example for what is working (sample data). And show us the steps you are taking. It might help address the problem.

Comment: You're right i was a bit unclear, i just updated the post and added the dicts im trying to plot!

Comment: Hi. *but when trying to call the function and plot all [...]*: what is your code for that?